# Position circles/bubbles along a chain of mountains

Tags: html, css, css-position

One of my current challenges is to position a varying number of circles/bubbles along a chain of mountains in an image using css. Let's assume the image would look like this (without the red bubbles):

[image: Mountain Chain with red bubbles]

The image always has to use the full width of the device (100% width). The resolution of the devices varies a lot (mobile phones, tablets, desktop computers).

Does anyone has an idea how to specify the position of the bubbles in css?

Or do you know a tool that performs a regression of the points of the mountain chain in order to use a function to calculate absolute positions of the points?

Comment: Try using absolute positioning with percentage values on `top`, `left`, ... offsets.

Comment: What is the the image format and how do you use it ( img tag, css background)?

Comment: @collapsar: currently I'm using a html img tag. But I'm open to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go down this route...

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.wrap img {
     width: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.item.i1 {
    left: 13%;
    top: 40%;
}

.item.i2 {
    left: 33%;
    top: 14%;
}

.item.i3 {
    left: 42%;
    top: 24%;
}

.item.i4 {
    left: 56%;
    top: 20%;
}

.item.i5 {
    left: 68%;
    top: 13%;
}

.item.i6 {
    left: 88%;
    top: 17%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .item {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        margin-left: -7px;
        margin-top: -7px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiRM2.png">
        
        <div class="item i1"></div>
        <div class="item i2"></div>
        <div class="item i3"></div>
        <div class="item i4"></div>
        <div class="item i5"></div>
        <div class="item i6"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/beyzaykd/)

Notice the media query to control dot size / positioning. This prevents overlapping and moving out of position.